# ReportViewer, передать параметр, на сервере отчетов

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer, report

Привязал отчет к WinForms, reportViewer. Теперь проблема, почему не получается передать параметр в отчет. Вот код :

```
 private void reportTripList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportParameter id_shift = new ReportParameter("id_sectionshift", "1932514");
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { id_shift });
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

В примере прописал значение отчета на прямую. К стати когда прописал блок кода с передачей параметров, отчет перестал генерироваться, просто пустое окно. Подскажите что делаю не так? Отчет лежит удаленно на сервере отчетов.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ получил [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/1ec88d3e-6dc4-4c76-b669-1cd684f89b20/reportviewer-?forum=fordesktopru). Вот решение :

> Видимо это. Для удаленных отчетов, нужно использовать свойство [ServerReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.serverreport.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)